# which process will be killed while OOM

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, out-of-memory, kill, syslog

One `openstack hypervisor node`(there is 50+ instances and about 20 instances's memory is 32GB) out of memory, and there are 10 virtual machines had been killed by `Out of memory killer`, the relevant `/var/log/syslog` show:

```
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957811.373994] Out of memory: Kill process 271615 (qemu-system-x86) score 166 or sacrifice child
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957811.374170] Killed process 271615 (qemu-system-x86) total-vm:139655772kB, anon-rss:131034236kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:20kB
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957812.386063] CPU 5/KVM invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x14040c0(GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_COMP), nodemask=(null), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
--
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957812.387464] Out of memory: Kill process 2584030 (qemu-system-x86) score 83 or sacrifice child
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957812.387600] Killed process 2584030 (qemu-system-x86) total-vm:69884796kB, anon-rss:66804252kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:8kB
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957813.455069] tp_librbd invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x14200ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), nodemask=(null), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
--
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957813.456292] Out of memory: Kill process 3147929 (qemu-system-x86) score 42 or sacrifice child
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957813.456429] Killed process 3147929 (qemu-system-x86) total-vm:35688736kB, anon-rss:33764600kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:16kB
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957814.503825] CPU 3/KVM invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x15000c0(GFP_KERNEL_ACCOUNT), nodemask=(null), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
--
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957814.505205] Out of memory: Kill process 4073671 (qemu-system-x86) score 41 or sacrifice child
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957814.505344] Killed process 4073671 (qemu-system-x86) total-vm:35707996kB, anon-rss:33637940kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:20kB
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957815.525479] CPU 6/KVM invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x15000c0(GFP_KERNEL_ACCOUNT), nodemask=(null), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
--
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957815.526818] Out of memory: Kill process 1357873 (qemu-system-x86) score 41 or sacrifice child
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957815.526960] Killed process 1357873 (qemu-system-x86) total-vm:35938384kB, anon-rss:32726864kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:20kB
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957816.544233] safe_timer invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x14200ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), nodemask=(null), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
--
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957816.545469] Out of memory: Kill process 2921291 (qemu-system-x86) score 41 or sacrifice child
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957816.545620] Killed process 2921291 (qemu-system-x86) total-vm:36576576kB, anon-rss:33261476kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:20kB
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957817.573469] service invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x14200ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), nodemask=(null), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
--
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957817.574694] Out of memory: Kill process 1356697 (qemu-system-x86) score 38 or sacrifice child
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957817.574846] Killed process 1356697 (qemu-system-x86) total-vm:35951776kB, anon-rss:27949424kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:4kB
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957818.624274] msgr-worker-0 invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x14200ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), nodemask=(null), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
--
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957818.625475] Out of memory: Kill process 2321706 (qemu-system-x86) score 37 or sacrifice child
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957818.625618] Killed process 2321706 (qemu-system-x86) total-vm:36566580kB, anon-rss:29917088kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:20kB
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957819.649223] apache2 invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x14200ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), nodemask=(null), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
--
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957819.650431] Out of memory: Kill process 1922663 (qemu-system-x86) score 21 or sacrifice child
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957819.650565] Killed process 1922663 (qemu-system-x86) total-vm:19312192kB, anon-rss:17027652kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:4kB
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957820.673261] magnum-conducto invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x14200ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), nodemask=(null), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
--
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957820.674482] Out of memory: Kill process 3521435 (qemu-system-x86) score 21 or sacrifice child
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957820.674680] Killed process 3521435 (qemu-system-x86) total-vm:19795968kB, anon-rss:17038100kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:4kB
Sep 30 16:01:29 os-node-32 kernel: [45957823.431014] brqc919803b-23: port 13(tap828cba7b-59) entered disabled state
```

I want to know which process will be killed while occurring `OOM`? What is that principle?

As the logs show, at the same time **Sep 30 16:01:29**, there are 10 process had been killed, and the first process is the most memory used 128G's instance -- `total-vm:139655772kB`, and then killed second memory used and so on, but the last two killed process are not memory used more than other instances which had not been killed.

Why it would kill so much process? if the 128G's instance was killed, the hypervisor will has enough memory.

Comment: Previously answered over on Unix.SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153585/how-does-the-oom-killer-decide-which-process-to-kill-first

Comment: @NateEldredge thx, but I have no idea about how oom kill such batch processes.